# Google Places API - How to load website upon selecting a location?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, webkit, google-places-api

I implemented the `pickPlace` function from the Google docs:

```
func pickPlace() {
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.708637, longitude: -74.014839)
    let northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: center.latitude + 0.001, longitude: center.longitude + 0.001)
    let southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: center.latitude - 0.001, longitude: center.longitude - 0.001)
    let viewport = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: northEast, coordinate: southWest)
    let config = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: viewport)
    let placePicker = GMSPlacePicker(config: config)

    placePicker.pickPlace(callback: {(place, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        if let place = place {
            self.navigationItem.title = place.name
            if let website = place.website {
                self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: website))
                self.view = self.webView
                print(website)
            }
            let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 40.708637, longitude: -74.014839, zoom: 18)

            let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
            self.view = mapView

        } else {
            self.navigationItem.title = "No place selected"
        }
    })
}
```

And added in the webView request inside the `if let website = place.website` conditional. When I run the app and select a place, the print statement is run with the proper URL, but the webView does not load. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Ultimately I'd like to be able to use the website outside of the pickPlace function, and use it in my `didTapWindowOf` function. Perhaps by initializing a variable like `var site: URL?` and setting place.website (unwrapped) to that. Then in `didTapWindowOf` I just just use `self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: site))`. But I'm relatively new and that approach isn't working for me so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The standard way to handle this would be to create another view controller which takes the URL to be loaded and displays the web view. Then when the user selects a place, you create an instance of that view controller and present it somehow. Replacing the current view is a very unusual approach.

Comment: I'll refactor to include another view controller, but I don't see how that will solve the current issue, which is getting `place.website` unwrapped and outside of that completion handler/function so I can use it around the app.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding your issue properly, but one common approach to that is to provide a completionHandler to the `pickPlace` method which takes a URL parameter. Once you have the website, you would call `completionHandler(website)`. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm not very used to completion handlers yet, I just have this one from Google's Places API docs. Basically my issue here is I'm trying to make it so I can set `place.website` (which is currently only available in this function, within the scope of the `if let` statement) to a variable like `website` or `site` or something, that I can use anywhere in my app.